# What dll to deploy with exe when Microsoft.Office reference is added in Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

I need to put a C# .NET 2.0 exe built in Visual Studio 2015 release mode to various computers ranging from Win 7 upto Windows 10 both 32 and 64 bit platforms. Win XP will be outdated soon so I am not considering it for deployment.

Below is the screenshot of all references added in my project. I have highlighted the Microsoft library references (not other 3rd party) that I added manually in the project.

[image: Visual Studio references]

The Exe is built in .NET 2.0 because FreeImageNET and itextSharp are in .NET 2.0 but I need addition Windows Office and scripting functionality so I have added extra references which I have highlighted in the image.

Please let me know what dll are required to be deployed along with exe, and also the folder where they should go? I mean should I put those in same folder as the exe in Program files, or put in System32, System etc.?

Please note the exe will be deployed as a software using Inno setup builder on all range on desktop Windows versions.

Dll that I already have included:

FreeImage.dll     (This is 3rd party library)
FreeImageNET.dll  (This is 3rd party library)
itextsharp.dll    (This is 3rd party library)

But what to add for System.Management, IWshRuntimeLibrary, Microsoft.Office.Core and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word? and which folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the /bin/Release/ folder underneath your project (assuming standard solution setup). That folder should contain all the files you need  (everything but what .NET provides. As long as you added all required DLLs as references in Visual Studio they should end up there.

Comment: But it doesn't put anything related to Microsoft.Office

Comment: Yeah, if you don't reference it in your code it won't always copy. One thing you can check is to see if the "copy local" flag is set for that reference  under properties.

Comment: Those DLLs might also be part of .NET, and therefore you don't need to provide them.